# Configuring SQL Server AlwaysOn in AWS

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, aws

Has anyone ever successfully created SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Group in a single subnet in AWS?
We have created a Windows Failover Cluster with two nodes but they are both in the same subnets.  So far everything with the AAG has worked with the exception of a failover.  We have added two different secondary IPs to each node that is assigned to the Availability Group Listener.

When do a failover, the secondary IP keeps trying to come online but it can't because of IP conflict.  After a few minutes then the resource would be up and running.  Is there anyone to speed this up so that it doesn't take so long for the cluster resource to get back online?

We are using Windows 2016 and SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition with SP1